# Excel 2013 Conditional formatting

Tags: excel

I am fetching values to sheet2 from sheet1 in Excel 2013 with a formula like:

```
='sheet1'!A8
```

In sheet1 that particular cell contains text like "**003 shopping center**" and is in bold. But in sheet2 I am getting normal text instead of bold. I used conditional formatting like:

```
=IF((ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A8,1))))
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use an `IF` here, the [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) expects a boolean:

```
=ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A8,1))
```